# Get-ComputerInfo fails on Windows 7

Tags: powershell

Should this work?

```
>$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.14409.1018

>(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise

>Get-ComputerInfo
Get-ComputerInfo : Unable to find an entry point named 'GetFirmwareType' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ComputerInfo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ComputerInfo], EntryPointNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.EntryPointNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetComputerInfoCommand
```

Comment: The [GetFirmwareType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfirmwaretype) function looks to need Windows 8 or above.

Comment: Reproducible with Win 7, 5.1 PowerShell.  With PowerShell 6 preview-3, it works as expected.  @boxdog is correct in that GetFirmwareType requires Windows 8+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be an issue with PowerShell 5.1 that wasn't corrected until PowerShell 6. I found [this bug report](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3023) on the PowerShell GitHub site. Bugs for PowerShell 6 are typically not backported to PowerShell 5.x.

There are several commands added in PS 5.1 that don't work at all on Windows 7. `Resolve-DnsName`, for example.